# pandas groupby: building multiple columns efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multi-index such that I can easily create a function that uses data from mutliple columns as input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('ALSN','VA.M'):range(5), ('ALSN','VB.M'):np.arange(5)+2,
                  ('ALVY','VA.M'):range(5), ('ALVY','VB.M'):np.arange(5)+20,
                  ('ALSN', 'VP.M'):np.arange(5)-10, ('ALVY','VP.M'):np.arange(5)-30,
                  ('ALGG', 'VP.M'):np.arange(5)/5.})

        ALGG    ALSN                    ALVY
        VP.M    VA.M    VB.M    VP.M    VA.M    VB.M    VP.M
0       0.0     0       2       -10     0       20      -30
1       0.2     1       3       -9      1       21      -29
2       0.4     2       4       -8      2       22      -28
3       0.6     3       5       -7      3       23      -27
4       0.8     4       6       -6      4       24      -26
```

I want to filter this, and then apply a function to, say, the VA.M and VB.M columns:

```
df2 = g.filter(lambda z: z.name[-1] != 'G')
df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda g: pd.Series(g[g.name]['VB.M']+g[g.name]['VA.M']))

    ALSN    ALVY
0   2       20
1   4       22
2   6       24
3   8       26
4   10      28
```

So, far so good.
However, what I really want to do is build a function that takes multiple columns as input (as above), but then outputs multiple columns.  So, for example, it could sum the VA.M and VB.M columns and then return the square root and cube root as new columns.

Clearly, I could do this with two different apply functions (compute the sum, then either the square or cube root), but I'd like to perform the intermediate step (compute the sum) only once.  Is that possible?

Additionally, I'd like the output to be stored back in the dataframe as, e.g., the columns ('ALSN', 'V2'), and ('ALSN', 'V3') can this be done at the sametime as the apply?  Or do I need to compute the V2 or V3 columns, then take the resulting dataframes and merge with the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy.

First find values of first level of `MultiIndex` by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then select by [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
lvl = df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
lvl = lvl[~lvl.str.contains('G')]
print (lvl)
Index(['ALSN', 'ALVY'], dtype='object')

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df2 = df.loc[:, idx[lvl, ['VA.M','VB.M']]]
print (df2)
  ALSN      ALVY     
  VA.M VB.M VA.M VB.M
0    0    2    0   20
1    1    3    1   21
2    2    4    2   22
3    3    5    3   23
4    4    6    4   24
```

Use `groupby` for each function and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)  with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (pd.concat([df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: (x**2).sum(axis=1)), 
                  df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: (x**3).sum(axis=1))],
                  keys=('x^2','x^3')).unstack(0))

  ALSN      ALVY       
   x^2  x^3  x^2    x^3
0    4    8  400   8000
1   10   28  442   9262
2   20   72  488  10656
3   34  152  538  12194
4   52  280  592  13888
```

Another very similar solution:

```
print (df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: (x**2)))
  ALSN      ALVY     
  VA.M VB.M VA.M VB.M
0    0    4    0  400
1    1    9    1  441
2    4   16    4  484
3    9   25    9  529
4   16   36   16  576

print (df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: (x**3)))
  ALSN      ALVY       
  VA.M VB.M VA.M   VB.M
0    0    8    0   8000
1    1   27    1   9261
2    8   64    8  10648
3   27  125   27  12167
4   64  216   64  13824
```

```
df21 = df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: (x**2).sum(axis=1))
df22 = df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: (x**3).sum(axis=1))
print (df21)
   ALSN  ALVY
0     4   400
1    10   442
2    20   488
3    34   538
4    52   592

print (df22)
   ALSN   ALVY
0     8   8000
1    28   9262
2    72  10656
3   152  12194
4   280  13888

print (pd.concat([df21,df22], keys=('x^2','x^3')).unstack(0))
  ALSN      ALVY       
   x^2  x^3  x^2    x^3
0    4    8  400   8000
1   10   28  442   9262
2   20   72  488  10656
3   34  152  538  12194
4   52  280  592  13888
```

EDIT by comment:

```
df = df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
print (df)
   ALSN  ALVY
0     2    20
1     4    22
2     6    24
3     8    26
4    10    28

df3 = pd.concat([df ** 2, df ** 3], keys=('x^2','x^3'), axis=1)
df3.columns = df3.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
df3 = df3.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df3)
  ALSN       ALVY       
   x^2   x^3  x^2    x^3
0    4     8  400   8000
1   16    64  484  10648
2   36   216  576  13824
3   64   512  676  17576
4  100  1000  784  21952
```

Comment: try not to use really complex apply; users will then think this is the right way to do things; iow your sol 2 is much better - it could be even better w/o the apply and use .sum() directly on the groups (a little tricky but possible)

Comment: @Jeff - thank you, I try it. I delete first solution.

Comment: @jezrael -- thanks for the suggestion!  two questions: (1) what version of pandas/numpy are you using? Mine is not happy with the .str in your line #2: ~lvl.str.contains('G') ; 2) in both of your solutions, you're applying the `x**2` or `x**3` before summing. What I want to do is perform the sum first, then the next operation, and ideally I don't want to compute the sum once total (not once before the `x**2` and then again before the `x**3`)

Comment: @SWallace  I use last version of pandas - `0.19.1`.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for this suggestion, I would not have come up with this on my own.  It's certainly not easy.  Interestingly, when I use the multiindex on a dataframe with ~2000 columns and apply this approach to generate ~200 new columns of data, its roughly 15% faster to simply iterate over non-hierarchical columns, instead using groupby to do the selection. That was a surprise to me.